# Медный век русской литературы

Tags: литературоведение

Существует ли самодостаточное и признанное понятие "Медный век русской литературы"? 
Если да, то каков его временной период, представители, характеристика?

В порядке пояснения- кросспост с другого ресурса (с сокращениями).

> Началось все с ерунды. Сегодня утром ради никчемного поста на не
>   слишком значимом ресурсе обдумывал фразу "автор Золотого Века написал
>   бы тут..." - ну и так далее - для нас совершенно не важно, что именно
>   он бы там написал.
>
> Дабы не оказаться неправильно понятым, решил уточнить, как понимают
>   период "Золотого века" современные авторы. Оказывается, классическое
>   "от рождения Пушкина до смерти Чехова" уже прочно забыто и многие
>   просто не знают этого выражения. Да и сам я вынужден признаться, что
>   за именем его автора (Антонович) я полез в википедию. На этом фоне
>   совершенно теряется понимание смысла названия периода "Серебряного
>   века" - и мне, как преданному почитателю "серебряных" авторов - едва ли
>   не всех без исключения, - это как-то обидно...
>
> Но это все присказка...
>
> Я набрел на несколько обсуждений о существовании некоего "медного
>   века" русской литературы. Вот тут меня точно оторопь взяла... Если
>   верить всяким-разным интернет-сплетням, то такое полуофициальное
>   название носил советский период (после Горького примерно) - и
>   незашоренные студенты-филологи изображали его видных представителей
>   зарисовками с натуры - в шкурах и с бронзовыми топорами...
>
> Буду рад любым **содержательным** комментариям по теме. Флуду рад не буду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Название действительно полуофициальное, но оно есть. Медный век - это **век авангарда.**

Мы привыкли делить культурные эпохи на Золотой (19 век), Серебряный (начало 20 века),  и сейчас вот появился  Бронзовый. Вводя в культурологический обиход это понятие, Слава Лён, идеолог, составитель и участник антологии «Бронзовый век русской поэзии» ( издание «Мировой академии русского стиха» .Издательство ВВМ / СПб 2013) , стремится провести непрерывающуюся кривую спадов и подъемов, объединяющую Золотой и Серебряный века русской поэзии с эпохой послесталинского возрождения русской культуры. В этом ряду Бронзовый век, который по мысли автора «проще было бы назвать каменным», а Анна Ахматова называла догутенберговским, ограничен периодом с 1953 по 1989 гг. Концепт Бронзового века был впервые заявлен в альманахе NEUE RUSSISCHE LITERATUR (NRL) – первом и единственном в СССР литературно-художественном альманахе, начавшем выходить в «там-издате»: в Австрии (Зальцбург, университет) на двух языках – русском и немецком. Открывался альманах «Малой антологией поэтов Бронзового века» – стихами: поэтов-квалитистов: Сосноры, Лёна, Хвостенко, Волохонского; поэтов-концептуалистов: Сапгира, Холина, Некрасова; поэтов-традиционалистов: Горбаневской и Бродского. В том же альманахе была опубликована проза Венедикта Ерофеева и Владимира Кормера, а также запрещённые в СССР филологические работы структуралистов: Бориса Гаспарова, Александра Жолковского и Михаила Щеглова.

Теоретики литературы пытаются дать целостную характеристику 20 века. Раньше мы говорили о символизме (10-е годы века), соцреализме(1917 - 20-е годы) и дальше по годам: 30-е, 40-е, 50-60-е, 70-80-е. Но эта хронология не отражает различные течения в эти годы. Есть литературный истеблишмент, есть внутренние эмигранты - диссиденты,сам-издат, там-издат и андеграунд, есть Русское зарубежье.   Наталья Крылова в работе "Медный век. Очерк теории и литературной практики Русского авангарда" пытается дать представление об авангарде как Медном веке - самостоятельной культурной эпохе.Она говорит, что что авангард и символизм — два равноправных течения в рамках единого направления — модернизма. У них имеются существенные совпадения мировоззренческих предпосылок, а также близкие художественные принципы.

Начало авангардного “прорыва” к новому искусству уместно датировать 1910 годом.  А. Блок писал: “Далее, 1910 год — это кризис символизма, о котором тогда очень много писали и говорили. В этом году явственно дали о себе знать направления, которые встали во враждебную позицию и к символизму, и друг к другу: акмеизм, эгофутуризм и первые начатки футуризма. Лозунгом первого из этих направлений был человек — но какой-то уже другой человек, вовсе без человечности, какой-то „первозданный Адам“”. Именно в 1910 году идейно и формально исчерпал себя символизм, задававший тон русскому искусству почти полтора десятилетия. Вторая граница более расплывчата: А. Флакер указывает 1929–1932 годы; можно было бы назвать и 1934 год — год Первого Всесоюзного съезда советских писателей, который один из современных критиков  назвал “коллективизацией советской литературы”. 1934 — год узаконивания совершенно нового типа культуры, обозначенного в исследовании В. Паперного “Культура Два”.  Мало кто из представителей Медного века переживет эту дату: в жерновах “революционных” репрессий в первую очередь оказались именно приверженцы революционного искусства.

Характерной особенностью Медного века является его художественный плюрализм и отсутствие центрального стилевого течения. Сопредельные с ним явления — символизм и соцреализм — были монокультурами по своему типу, они не терпели ответвлений и внутренних членений. Авангард изначально был отмечен соревновательностью образовавших его литературных школ, среди которых наиболее значительными следует признать акмеизм, футуризм, имажинизм, литературный конструктивизм, группы “Серапионовы братья” и ОБЭРИУ. Теоретическое объединение ОПОЯЗ разработало принципы нового авангардного литературоведения.

https://refdb.ru/look/1652757-pall.html

Медный - это не историческая хронология, это взято из оценки по Овидию: Золотой век - тепло,справедливость, безопасность, мир, благополучие - идеал добра, честности, долга; Серебряный - "зиму, лето и осень Зевс отделил от краткой весны: то зной стоял над землёй, обезвлаживая и раскаляя воздух, то цепенела земля от страшного северного ветра", противоречия, антагонизм я-мы, борьба, религиозность; Медный - суровый,противостояние, но преступности нет, нет и безбожия; Железный - коварство, насилие, война, грабёж, корыстолюбие. Имелось в виду, что Медный век - противостояние по отношению к прошлым культурам (классике, символизму) и неприятие тёмных сторон наступающего"страшного" века.

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо. Хотя немного не понял, Считают ли авторы "Бронзовый" и "Медный" одним и тем же. Для меня так это единое понятие.

Comment: Ну и про Овидия - тоже понятно. Хотя помнится, еще и на Ветхий Завет кто-то делал отсылки. Может и ошибаюсь.

Comment: Нет, Бронзовый век - хронологическое понятие, то, что после смерти Сталина, а Медный - это только авангард до  Первого Всесоюзного съезда советских писателей, до “коллективизации советской литературы”, который уничтожил все авангардные литературные группы, до того, как литература стала "колёсиком и винтиком одного -единственного..." , потом авангард проявится в творчестве концептуалистов, структуролистов, но это уже не то, не возрождение свободного творчества, это "выверты" индивидуалистов.

Comment: Понимаете, в чем дело. В вашей интерпретации "Медный" как понятие - это что-то совсем недавнее, неологизм... А "Бронзовый", который  "после Сталина" (пусть будет так, хотя я считал, что раньше) - это придумано явно не вчера. И скорее всего до определенного момента "медный" и "бронзовый" не различали (это не только в литературоведении проблема). И дело не в хронологии, путаница эта в головах. Получается, что в ваших формулировках, мне нужно интересоваться веком Бронзовым. Но в любом случае - спасибо.

Comment: Вообще, понятием Бронзового века принято определять либо культуру второго русского модернизма, сложившуюся в 1950-е годы и просуществовавшую до 1980-х годов, когда отечественная литература вступила в эпоху постмодерна, либо – в более  широкой трактовке – вообще современную культуру.
В понимании школьной программы это будут шестидесятники: А. А. Вознесенский, Е. А. Евтушенко, Б. Ш. Окуджава, Б. А. Ахмадулина..Но это не совсем корректно, это поэты Политехнического, совсем другой пласт. Кто-то относит сюда же лейтенантскую прозу и поэзию Политехнического. Вот Бродский - да,Заболоцкий.

Comment: http://svpressa.ru/culture/article/127398/  
https://history.wikireading.ru/398491